# $(A\setminus B) \subset (V_A \setminus K_A \cup K_A \setminus V_B \cup V_B \setminus K_B)$ for $K_A\subset A \subset V_A$ , $K_B\subset B \subset V_B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading the proof of the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani-Theorem from Rudin.
I'm having trouble to understand the following set-inequality.

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$. Furthermore let $K_A,K_B,V_A,V_V$ be subsets of $X$ such that $K_A \subset A \subset V_A$ and $K_B \subset B \subset V_B$.
Then the claim is, that $$(A \setminus B) \subset (V_A \setminus K_B) \subset (V_A \setminus K_A) \cup (K_A \setminus V_B) \cup (V_B \setminus K_B)$$.

While it's clear that $$(A \setminus B) \subset (V_A \setminus K_B)$$ since $A \subset V_A$ and $K_B \subset B$ I cannot see why $$(V_A \setminus K_B) \subset (V_A \setminus K_A) \cup (K_A \setminus V_B) \cup (V_B \setminus K_B)$$ should hold.

**Update:**
I think I found what I was looking for.
$$
\begin{align}
V_A \setminus K_B 
&\subset
(V_A \setminus K_A \cup K_A) \setminus K_B\\
&=
(V_A \setminus K_A\setminus K_B) \cup (K_A \setminus K_B)\\
&\subset
(V_A \setminus K_A) \cup (K_A \setminus K_B)\\
&\subset
(V_A \setminus K_A) \cup ((K_A\setminus V_B \cup V_B) \setminus K_B)\\
&=
(V_A \setminus K_A) \cup (K_A\setminus V_B \setminus K_B) \cup (V_B \setminus K_B)\\
&\subset
(V_A \setminus K_A) \cup (K_A\setminus V_B) \cup (V_B \setminus K_B)
\end{align}
$$

Where I've repeatetly used that $X \subset (X \setminus Y) \cup Y$ for arbitrary sets $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Just take any point on the left side and show that it belongs to the right side.

Comment: Well, that's clearly what I need to demonstrate. However, since there are no further explanations as to why this should be the case, I assume that some simple set algebraic rules lead to the inclusion.

Comment: Take $x$ in LHS and consider the cases $x \in K_a, x \notin K_A, x \in V_B, x \notin V_B$

Comment: I was looking for a solution which was more in the spirit of what I've added.

Comment: Instead of $X \subset X \setminus Y \cup Y$ write $X \subset (X \setminus Y) \cup Y$. Otherwise, what you have done is fine.